# Initializing commands C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

```
    private readonly ICommand onSelectIssueCommand = null;

    public ICommand OnSelectedIssueCommand
    {
        get { return onSelectIssueCommand ?? new Command<object>(OnEventSelected); }
    }
```

I'm trying to find out the best way to initialize commands, I really like this way but someone recently told me this was wrong. I haven't had any problems with it whatsoever but I would like to learn the best way to do it. 
Mainly use commands in xamarin-mobile development context

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Comment: What more would you like to know? I'm just wondering if this is an acceptable way to initalize my commands?

Comment: But this isn't initializing anything. `onSelectIssueCommand` always remains `null`.

Comment: Really? But then it shouldn't be working at all. Maybe it gets initalized during the xamarin initalizecomponent stage? Seems like that always enters it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this way always creating a new Command when the getter is called ?

I would have done something like this :

```
private ICommand onSelectIssueCommand = null;

public ICommand OnSelectedIssueCommand
{
    get 
    { 
        if (onSelectIssueCommand == null)
            onSelectIssueCommand = new Command<object>(OnEventSelected);
        return onSelectIssueCommand;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically it is called every time the getter is called, but shoudln't the getter only be called once during initalization of pages?

Comment: You may need to call it again if you need to raise the CanExecuteChanged event.

Comment: Good Point! Didn't think about that